# Not rendered pois on OpenStreetMap

Tags: openstreetmap, point-of-interest

There are a few poi that I can see on Josm that are not rendered to the final map. OSM database contains them at least for some month. I can' figure out why the doesn't appear on the map.

Example poi ids:

```
2022172177
2011325312
1579653536
1572586097
1750804585
```

Any idea?

Thanks,

Hubi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the tags are not recognised by renderer. Can you give ID-s/URL-s of the POIs to check this out?

Edit: you can check from http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:historic which historic tags have rendering. These ones seem to have it undefined.

Comment: I edited original post and added ids.

Answer (score 1):

See [key:historic](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key%3ahistoric). Not all values of that key have renderings in the default style.